# Converting elisp unixtime into js-date object

Tags: c, json, datetime, emacs, elisp

for a specific application I need to handle elisp internal unix time date format in Javascript. Elisp (current-time) comes with this special format:

> current-time is a built-in function in `editfns.c'.
>   (current-time)
>
> Return the current time, as the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00.
>   The time is returned as a list of integers (HIGH LOW USEC PSEC).
>   HIGH has the most significant bits of the seconds, while LOW has the
>   least significant 16 bits.  USEC and PSEC are the microsecond and
>   picosecond counts.

So i´m getting a time string: `[21039,58064,0]` (json representation of `(21039 58064 0)`). How can i convert this into a JS `Date` Object with javascript? Its easy in emacs, but this is not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Date(21039 * Math.pow(2, 16) + 58064);
```

Note that you don't need to write it exactly this way, `Math.pow(2, 16)` because this is a constant expression. This is so you could understand what is going on.

Also note that you can't use bitwise operations on floats (`Number`s larger then 2^32 in JavaScript parlance). So you have to multiply instead of shifting and sum instead of "or"ing.

Comment: that did work for me. had to multiply the result by 1000 though to get the right unixtime ...

Comment: @zip Oh, yes, right, this should be milliseconds, not seconds.